Porque el titulo de tabla se divide en 2 párrafos?
Estaba haciendo unas practicas de etiquetas para revisar que tan bien recuerdo html 5 cuando encuentro este error
El titulo "tabla 2" se recorre en 2 parrafos, sin razon aparente

Este este es el texto html:


<table>
  <caption>tabla 2</caption>

  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>




Porque el caption se ajusta al ancho de la tabla, y la palabra sobrepasa ese ancho creando 2 líneas de texto.
Una solución es ajustar el caption para que cubra el máximo posible con width: max-content;


caption{
 width: max-content;
}
<table>
  <caption>tabla 2</caption>

  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>



